# How to remove duplicate rows in python datagram and assign to a new datagram but keep the original raw data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I'm,new to python and do the mistake of coding python like I would do SAS. Is there a way to remove duplicate rows based on a set of keys from a data frame and assign it to a new datagram while keeping the original raw data frame

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? You're expected to [try to solve your problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). If you get stuck then it's a good idea to ***ask a specific question*** here based on your own solution attempt; providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

let df be your original dataframe, then:

```
import pandas as pd

#create a new df with duplicate rows removed
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)
```